# Delete or create users on slack without admin scopes

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api

I want to delete and create user on slack workspace by creating a slack bot but I am not able to do it is giving error `missing scope.` I want to do it without adding admin scopes but not able to get how I can do it.

I have tried it by adding
Bot token scopes: `"im:read", "im:write", "mpim:write", "channels:history", "channels:manage", "channels:read", "chat:write", "team:read", "users:read", "users:write", "users:read.email", "reactions:read", "chat:write.public",`.

Bot users scopes `"channels:write", "channels:history", "chat:write", "channels:read", "users:write", "users:read", "users:read.email", "team:read", "reactions:read", "im:write", "mpim:write",`.

but got error `missing scope`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

The API methods capable of doing that [admin.users.invite](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.users.invite) and [admin.users.remove](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.users.remove) requires the [admin.users:write](https://api.slack.com/scopes/admin.users:write) scope. And according to the documentation, to obtain this scope, the app requiring it must be installed by an admin or Owner:

> This admin scope is obtained through version two of the OAuth V2 flow,
> but there are a few additional requirements. The app requesting this
> scope must be installed by an admin or Owner of an Enterprise Grid
> organization. Also, the app must be installed on the entire org, not
> on an individual workspace. See below for more details.